# laravel Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel, image

can't store image it's always say can't write image data 
error: Can't write image data to path (E:\work\iShop-Admin-backend\storage/app/public/images/p/4069/11016/4069_11016_600x600.jpg)
my code :

```
            $destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/public/images/p/' . $product->id_product . '/';

        if (!File::exists($destinationPath)) {
            File::makeDirectory($destinationPath);
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i<=6; $i++){
            if($row["image_{$i}"] != "")
                $value = $row["image_{$i}"];
            $contents = file_get_contents($value);
            $imageBase64 = base64_encode($contents);
            $filetype = \File::extension($value);
            //$ext = ltrim($filetype, 'image/');
            $ext = 'image/' . $filetype;
            $media = 'data:' . $ext . ';base64,' . $imageBase64;

            //Log::info($media);
            //Log::info($ext);

            if (!empty($media)) {

                $position = ProductImage::where('id_product', $product->id_product)->max('position');
                $data = array(
                    'id_product' => $product->id_product,
                    'position' => $position ? $position + 1 : 1,
                    'extension' => '.' . $filetype
                );
                if ($i == 1) {
                    $data['cover'] = 1;
                } else {
                    $data['cover'] = 0;
                }
                $image = ProductImage::create($data);
                LogController::log('STORE', 'catalog/product/upload/' . $product->id_product, $product->id_product, 'PRODUCT', 'add image to product where id_product=' . $product->id_product, null, $image);
                if (!File::exists($destinationPath . $image->id_image)) {
                    File::makeDirectory($destinationPath . $image->id_image);

                    $destinationPath = $destinationPath . $image->id_image . '/';
                    $height = Image::make($media)->height();
                    $width = Image::make($media)->width();


                    Image::make($media)->resize(600, 600)->save($destinationPath . $product->id_product . '_' . $image->id_image . '_600x600' . '.' . $filetype);
                    Image::make($media)->resize(270, 270)->save($destinationPath . $product->id_product . '_' . $image->id_image . '_270x270' . '.' . $filetype);
                    Image::make($media)->resize(140, 140)->save($destinationPath . $product->id_product . '_' . $image->id_image . '_140x140' . '.' . $filetype);
                    Image::make($media)->resize(80, 80)->save($destinationPath . $product->id_product . '_' . $image->id_image . '_80x80' . '.' . $filetype);

                    $destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/public/images/p/' . $product->id_product . '/';
                }

            }

        }
```

how to solve it ?

Comment: You overcomplicated things - why are you converting to base64? Anyhow - I think [this should help](https://laravel.io/forum/04-05-2014-cant-write-image-data-to-path) - Instead of using relative path use absolute path, ie. `Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(600, 600)->save($path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with this, you need to make sure the folder path exists and which has right permissions set.

```
$relPath = 'img/product/';
    if (!file_exists(public_path($relPath))) {
        mkdir(public_path($relPath), 777, true);
    }
```

Where `$relPath` is the path relative to `public` directory.

This requirement is however windows specific. In linux, folder directory will be created if it does not exist.